# Maximum number of ways of splitting a set of points with an hyperplane

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, extremal-combinatorics

Given a set $S$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $D_S$ be the set 
$\{\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{u'}|: \mathbf{u},\mathbf{u'}\in S\}$ (where $\forall i=1,2,\ldots, d$, $\mathbf{v}_i=|\mathbf{u}_i-\mathbf{u'}_i|$). Thus, we have $|D_S|\le{{n}\choose{2}}$.

Given any vector $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\mathbf{w}_i>0$ $\forall i=1,2,\ldots, d$ (i.e. belonging to the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^d$), consider now the binary "labelling" function 
$f_\mathbf{w}:D_S\to\{0,1\}$ defined as 
$f_{\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{v})=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{v}\ge 0}$ (i.e. for all $\mathbf{v}\in D_S$, if $\mathbf{w}^{\top}\mathbf{v}\ge 0$ then $f_{\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{v})=1$, otherwise $f_{\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{v})=0$).

---

**Question**: What is the maximum number (expressed as a function of $n$ and $d$), over all possible sets $S\in\mathbb{R}^d$, of distinct binary labellings of the points of $D_S$ that one can obtain through $f_{\mathbf{w}}$ varying $\mathbf{w}$ within the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, the maximum is at least $n^{d-1} e^{\Omega(\sqrt{\log n})}$, because there are at least that many halving hyperplanes. This is a result of Géza Tóth.

Comment: I am also interested in finding a (possibly tight) upper bound.

Comment: I am referring to: Tóth, Géza. "Point sets with many $k$-sets." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 26, no. 2 (2001): 187-194. [Journal link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004540010022).

Comment: Thanks @Joseph.

Comment: Is it easy to answer for $d=2$?

Comment: @Gerry No, it is also open, the best bound is $O(n^{4/3})$ due to Dey. See this link: http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/open/ksets.html

Comment: If $S$ forms a grid, then $f_w$ are known as *threshold functions*, which have actively studied.

Comment: Actually $f_\mathbf{w}$ is maps elements of $D_S$ to $\{0,1\}$. I don't think that there exists any set $S$ such that $D_S$ forms a grid.